# How to achieve spiking effect on typography like Impulse Festival?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I was wondering how this effect was achieved. Does anybody have an idea how this would be possible using Adobe Illustrator or some other vector-based tool (I think this makes sense if you want to create a logo).

[image: Impulse Theater Festival Logo]

Answer (score 4):

- After typing the text, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
  <kbd>O</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
  Win to convert it to outlines
- Go to menu **Object** → **Path** → **Add Anchor Points** twice
- Select the text with the **Direct Selection Tool**
- Use the **Scallop Tool** [image], double click the tool to set a big size brush and click over the text to make the effect

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Looks like that is exactly what has been used.